# Am I solving these initial value problem correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was just hoping someone could check my work and tell me if I'm solving these types of problems correctly?

[image: I want to learn mathjax] [(Large image version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtwzh.jpg)

Comment: What is the inital value problem?

Comment: it is $\frac{dy}{dt}=-y+5$?

Comment: Sorry, yes @Dr.SonnhardGraubner that is the initial value problem

Comment: where is initial condition?

Comment: @Chiranjeev There is none. We are suppose to plug in different initial conditions, after we have solved the problem, and see what happens graphically.

Comment: pic is not clear, it seems , you did a mistake in 3rd step

Comment: An initial value problem usually consists of a differential equation and initial conditions on the solution and/or derivatives of the solution which single out some specific solution out of the general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your third step, you factor out a minus sign from $\frac 1{-y+5}$. The result should be $-\frac 1{y-5}$, but you wrote $-\frac 1{y+5}$. So replace the later $+5$'s with $-5$, and when you transpose it to the other side it becomes $+5$ rather than $-5$.

You use $x=\pm e^{-c}$. You explain this badly, by first saying $x=\pm e^{c}$ then later replacing $x^{-1}$ with $x$. The easiest way to correct this is to do the line replacing $(y-5)^{-1}$ with $y-5$ first then defining $x$ correctly.

Last, $x$ is a lousy name for a constant; it looks like another independent variable distinct from $t$. You already used $C$ earlier, so you could use something like $D$. I would replace the earlier uses of $C$ with $C'$ so I could use $C$ in my final answer.

With those changes, the final answer is

> $$y=Ce^{-t}+5$$

Substituting that into your original differential equation shows that it is correct. You should have done that with your attempted answer!

There is one more technical problem, that your method of solution ignores the possibility that $y=5$. When that is the case, you divide by zero in your steps. The later replacement of $\pm e^{-C'}$ with $C$ reintroduces that possibility, so your final answer is correct--but you got there by committing two opposing errors that canceled each other out. Those particular errors are commonly done in early differential equation solving, so your homework grader will probably overlook it. But I thought you should know about it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-y+5$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{-y+5}=\int dt$$

$$-\int\frac{dy}{y-5}=\int dt$$

$$-ln|y-5|=t+c$$

$$ln|y-5|=-t-c$$

$$y-5=e^{-t-c}$$